# FindClusters Hamming Distance giving error

Tags: cluster-analysis, binary, distance

I am trying to run `FindClusters[hex, DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8], IntegerDigits[0, 2, 8]] &]` over a list of data but I keep getting the error
[image]

(`the number of cluster DistanceFunction ... can only be either a positive integer or automatic`)

There is no problem running `FindClusters[hex]` or `FindClusters[hex, DistanceFunction -> CanberraDistance]`

I have also tried using `DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance[BaseForm[#, 2], BaseForm[16^^0, 2]] &`
`DistanceFunction -> HammingDistance[#, 16^^0] &`

Sort of at a loss as to what to try next. Any suggestions?

My data is just a list of integers. e.g. `{85,137,229,...}`

Comment: Try scoping the pure function `DistanceFunction -> (HammingDistance[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8], 
    IntegerDigits[0, 2, 8]] &)`

Comment: That did it! Thank you! What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: I guess as a followup, this puts everything in 1 cluster. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Ah nvm just need to put the number of partitions between `hex` and `dist..`

Comment: @skyfire you ran into an operator precedence issue. I have learned from experience that pure functions given on the right-hand-side of rules / options are best wrapped in `(  )` to make sure that the `&` operator binds to the right thing, i.e. `OptionName -> (something something &)`.